# Missing chunks of line

Tags: tables, line

This is the code for a three column table. Upon compilation the last two vertical lines of the table are not displayed correctly (i.e. the lines are not continous). I would appreciate very much if anyone can help me to get it right.

Kind regards
Thank you in advance
Miguel

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Something} & \textbf{Something} & \textbf{Something} \\ 
\hline
& & f\\
\hline
a & \multirow{4}{*}{e} & \multirow{4}{*}{f} \\
b \\
c & & \\
d & & \\
\hline
a & \multirow{4}{*}{e} & \multirow{4}{*}{f} \\
b \\
c & & \\
d & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Two `&`s are missing on lines 4 and 8

Answer (score 1):

You have to have something in each column, even if it is just blank. So your `b` rows should be set as

```
b & & \\
```

just as you set the `c` and `d` rows e.g.,

```
c & & \\
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` tries to improve the typesetting of tabular and mathematical matrices. It provides the environment `{NiceTabular}`. With that environment, the vertical rules will be drawn even when you don't put all the ampersands (`&`) in a row.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Something} & \textbf{Something} & \textbf{Something} \\ 
\hline
& & f\\
\hline
a & \multirow{4}{*}{e} & \multirow{4}{*}{f} \\
b \\
c & & \\
d & & \\
\hline
a & \multirow{4}{*}{e} & \multirow{4}{*}{f} \\
b \\
c & & \\
d & & \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]